# Подмена контента через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

У нас есть основной сайт: site.ru, также мы создали отдельный поддомен sub.site.ru и сделали его синонимом основного домена.

Теперь когда заходишь по адресу sub.site.ru видишь основной сайт без редиректа на основной домен.

Теперь необходимо сделать так, что если зашли через поддомен (sub.site.ru), то показывать файл из директории `/sub/index.php`, но чтобы в url это не отражалось.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать через htaccess?

Comment: Если синоним уже не нужен, то уберите его, и сделайте отдельный. зачем теперь сверху наворачивать костыль какой-то?

Comment: Где тут костыль?  И где я написал, что синоним не нужен.

Нужно, чтобы пользователь заходил на сайт с отельного поддомена, и ему подгружался раздел с основного сайта. В url не должно быть директории в которой находимся, но поддомен должен остаться.